# Why this imply that $Cov(X,Y)>0$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, covariance

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables such that the 2dimension random variable $(X,Y)$ is not continuous. why this imply that   $$Cov(X,Y)>0$$

I tried to use the definition on expected value so
$$Cov(X,Y)=E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$$
$$E[XY]=\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{\infty}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{0}} P(XY>t)dt\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}\displaystyle-\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{0}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{- \infty}} P(XY\leq t)dt\,$$

\begin{equation}
E[X]E[Y]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} xf_x(x)dx \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}yf_y(y)dy
\end{equation}

How do I procced from here? may I say that $x=y=t$?

Comment: May i ask why you think the implication is true?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous and $(X,Y)$ discontinuous with $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) > 0$, then $X$ and $-Y$ are also continuous and $(X,-Y)$ is discontinuous, but $\operatorname{Cov}(X,-Y) < 0$.

Comment: You right I don't know what did I think to my self, this is just imply they not necescery independent. thank you for this note